# SQL Server CE Insert/Update Multiple Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am trying to insert huge multiple rows in a single transaction. But the SQL Server database is not getting reflected with the update. Below is my code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
    Database1DataSet.Table1DataTable dt  = new Database1DataSet.Table1DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        dt.AddTable1Row(i.ToString(), "name" + i.ToString());
    }
    // Open the connection using the connection string.
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            cmd.CommandText = "Table1";
            var rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable)
            var rec = rs.CreateRecord();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                rec.SetString(0, dr["ID"].ToString());
                rec.SetString(1, dr["Name"].ToString());
                rs.Insert(rec);
            }
            rs.Close();
            rs.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }                            
    }
}
```

Comment: suggest you log any exceptions rather than ignoring them...

Comment: Hi Mitch, I am not getting any exception.

Comment: Look in your bin/debug folder for the database with data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html